# How to name such grouping behaviour?

Tags: behaviour, sociality, collective-behaviour

Under which keyword would you try to find out more about the grouping behaviour which looks like this? Does anybody recognizes such behaviour, or know an animal species which uses it?

My tries: **threshold group behaviour** (threshold here is the group size - if bigger than 5 individuals == stable), or **gravitational group behaviour**?

[image]

After **step 6** the group disintegrates (for example due to foraging) and mechanism starts by **step 1**. Important thing is that the location of forming stable group is **always different**.

Comment: You can check [this](http://beheco.oxfordjournals.org/content/13/1/20.full) paper out. I used the keyword "pack size threshold"

Comment: Hi @WYSIWYG! Close, but no cigar. Did you know any other examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't think it's precisely the behaviour you are asking about, you might also be interested in slime molds (e.g., Dictyostelium or Myxogastria). They start out as motile single cell organisms, have limited 'vision' (chemical cues), coalesce into a large multicellular structure when resources become limiting, and then disperse from (usually) a fruiting body.This is an example of "emergent collective behaviour".

Other searches you may want to try are "Biased random walk models" and "Shoaling behaviour".

Although pretty heavy, these papers may contain a formal mathematical description of the model you are after:

- Akira Okubo, 1986, doi: 10.1016/0065-227X(86)90003-1
- Angela Stevens and Hans G. Othmer, 1997, doi: 10.1137/S0036139995288976

Comment: After reading about emergent behavior and previously shoaling(aka schooling), I don't think those apply. When I answered this question, I original did some digging into schooling as well but concluded it doesn't fit. A discrete agent based model can be represented as a random walk so you didn't add anything new.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is a type of [fission-fusion society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission%E2%80%93fusion_society) or even some hybrid with [agent based](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2639936/) modeling.

> In ethology, a fission–fusion society is one in which the size and composition of the social group change as time passes and animals move throughout the environment; animals merge (fusion)—e.g. sleeping in one place—or split (fission)—e.g. foraging in small groups during the day. For species that live in fission–fusion societies, group composition is a dynamic property [[fission-fusion society]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission%E2%80%93fusion_society).

A classical example is the Bonobo or pigmy chimp.

1. [Bonobo - Pigmy Chimpanzee](https://www.msu.edu/~bondemil/bonobo.htm)
2. [Sociobiology](https://books.google.com/books?id=FEsCBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=animals%20that%20form%20groups%20break%20up%20to%20forage%20and%20then%20reform&source=bl&ots=1QNpl5ltNb&sig=EIYAZqT-aZU_LHD5zAiDs7Zr-AM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wPjTVITvDIvasATozYDYAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=animals%20that%20form%20groups%20break%20up%20to%20forage%20and%20then%20reform&f=false)
3. [The Social Behavior of Chimpanzees and Bonobos](http://primate.uchicago.edu/Stanford.pdf)